# Developing Springboot Application using Intellij IDEA - Ultimate Version 2018

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA ultimate version 2018 for developing and Springboot Application. Although the application is started when running the main application, the IDE shows errors for getters and setters.

The error is:

**Can't resolve method '......'**

Since I my subscription was expired , I moved to this version. As I think, the IDE matters for this error. Can someone help me out regarding this matter?

Comment: Use Spring Tool Suit which given added advantage while using Spring based application.

Comment: Are you using Lombok?

Comment: @HarshMishra yes, I am using Lombok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Lombok in this project which IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support out of the box.

You need to install this plug-in: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok